# Make Custom Directshow fiter to accept Parameters

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directshow, graphedit

I Created a CTransformFilter, this is used to Resize the output video. It is working with default values which i gave in the code.

Is it possible to make this filter receive values, i mean when i create Instance of this filter in my code is it possible to pass the values say like

Resizer->width = 100

Resizer->height = 50

here Resizer is the filter.

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement a "private interface" on your filter and then the controlling application will use it to communicate with the filter.

See [using methods of filter from dll file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/8144aec3-49ee-4caf-a815-f0e7619ff180) for details discussed in a similar question.