# Edit Settings Programatically of DirectShow Settings

Tags: c#, wpf, com, directshow, mediaelement

I am using MediaElement to show a video stream using DirectShow filters.
In GraphEdit I can modify the settings of each of the filters. 
What I am looking for is the possibility to set these values programmatically.

I have found the OleCreatePropertyFrame to open the property pages but I want to set these properties without opening the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties of individual filters, but in general you need to know the COM interfaces you need to use for specific filters.

`OleCreatePropertyFrame` basically does exactly the mentioned, just asking the filters first what property pages are applicable to specific filter (and then the page and the filter agree on how to load/save values, that is pages "know" which COM interfaces to use).

See related:

- [Set properties of filter in DirectShow.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265420/set-properties-of-filter-in-directshow-net/23278110#23278110)
- [Alternative way to program instead of using ISpecifyPropertyPages in Directshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382798/alternative-way-to-program-instead-of-using-ispecifypropertypages-in-directshow)
- [DirectShow: how to change filter properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375690/directshow-how-to-change-filter-properties)
- [Make Custom Directshow fiter to accept Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211953/make-custom-directshow-fiter-to-accept-parameters)